# Dagger + Retrofit dynamic URL

Tags: android, retrofit, dagger, retrofit2, dagger-2

**PROBLEM**

I need to call API from domains entered by USER and I need to edit my `Retrofit` singleton before the call accordingly to the inserted data.

Is there a way to "reset" my singleton, forcing it to recreate?

or

Is there a way to update my `baseUrl` with my data (maybe in Interceptor?) just before call?

**CODE**

*Singletons*

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Retrofit provideRetrofit(SharedPreferences prefs) {

    String apiUrl = "https://%1s%2s";
    apiUrl = String.format(apiUrl, prefs.getString(ACCOUNT_SUBDOMAIN, null), prefs.getString(ACCOUNT_DOMAIN, null));

    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new HeaderInterceptor())
            .build();

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(apiUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
API provideAPI(Retrofit retrofit) {
    return retrofit.create(API.class);
}
```

*API*

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("endpoint")
Observable<Response> logIn(@Field("login") String login, @Field("password") String password);
```

**How it works now**

Well the idea was to save user domain data via `SharedPrefs` before API call and modify `baseUrl` with formatted String.

Comment: This is all your singleton ? Where do you do your `retrofit.create()` ?

Comment: Yes this is the singleton responsible for providing retrofit for my presenters. I do have more singletons but they are not connected to the problem. EDIT: I've added my create() singleton to question code.

Comment: Have try to do like, `baseUrl()` and in your request `@POST("{url}")`, then url equals to an arguments to your function like, `@Path("url") String url` ? Just an idea. Can you show how do you make a call to your API ?

Comment: I think the only way to instert full url via annotation in API interface is with `@URL` and that can be used only in `@GET` calls.

Comment: `provideRetrofit` does way too much. Providing the url, the okhttp client, and each of the 2 call adapters and the header interceptor should all be its own method

Comment: @JakubW Not only on `@GET` calls. I am using this approach with `@Url` annotation right now with my `@POST` calls and I replaced it with overhead implementation of HostInterceptor + OkHttp + Dagger in my case. But solution above still can be useful when you want to change host only except whole path.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63076030/7511020 look into here

Comment: Can anybody please point me to "year 2023" solution? With Hilt injection.

Comment: @Micer this is most up to date solution -> https://www.baeldung.com/retrofit-dynamic-url

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I see 2 options here:

- Use dagger as it is intended. Create for every `baseUrl` their own `Retrofit` client, or
- Use an interceptor to modify the request before sending it

## Dagger approach

If you were to brute force urls, this would probably not be the right choice, since it relies on creating a new `Retrofit` instance for each.

Now every time the url changes, you just recreate the following demonstrated `UrlComponent` by supplying it with a new `UrlModule`.

### Clean up

Clean your `@Singleton` module, so that it provides `GsonConverterFactory`, and `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` to make proper use of dagger and not recreate shared objects.

```
@Module
public class SingletonModule {

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  GsonConverterFactory provideOkHttpClient() {/**/}

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  RxJavaCallAdapterFactory provideOkHttpClient() {/**/}
}


@Singleton
@Component(modules = SingletonModule.class)
interface SingletonComponent {

    // sub component
    UrlComponent plus(UrlModule component);
}
```

### Url Scoped

Introduce a `@UrlScope` to scope your `Retrofit` instances.

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UrlScope {
}
```

Then create a subcomponent

```
@SubComponent(modules=UrlModule.class)
public interface UrlComponent {}
```

And a module for it

```
@Module
class UrlModule {

    private final String mUrl;

    UrlModule(String url) { mUrl = url; }

    @Provides
    String provideUrl() {
        return mUrl;
    }

    @Provides
    @UrlScope
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(String url) {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
    }

    @Provides
    @UrlScope
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient client) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder().build();
    }

}
```

### Use scoped `Retrofit`

Instantiate the component and use it.

```
class Dagger {

    public void demo() {
        UrlModule module = new UrlModule(/*some url*/);
        SingletonComponent singletonComponent = DaggerSingletonComponent.create();
        UrlComponent urlComponent = singletonComponent.plus(module);

        urlComponent.getRetrofit(); // done.
    }
}
```

---

## OkHttp approach

Provide a properly scoped interceptor (`@Singleton` in this case) and implement the corresponding logic.

```
@Module
class SingletonModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    GsonConverterFactory provideGsonConverter() { /**/ }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    RxJavaCallAdapterFactory provideRxJavaCallAdapter() { /**/ }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    MyApiInterceptor provideMyApiInterceptor() { /**/ }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(MyApiInterceptor interceptor) {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient client) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder().build();
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = SingletonModule.class)
interface SingletonComponent {

    Retrofit getRetrofit();

    MyApiInterceptor getInterceptor();
}
```

***todo*** Implement the `MyApiInterceptor`. You will need to have a *setter* for the base url, and then just rewrite / modify the requests coming through.

Then, again, just go ahead and use it.

```
class Dagger {

    public void demo() {
        SingletonComponent singletonComponent = DaggerSingletonComponent.create();
        MyService service = singletonComponent.getRetrofit().create(MyService.class);
        MyApiInterceptor interceptor = singletonComponent.getInterceptor();

        interceptor.setBaseUrl(myUrlA);
        service.doA();
        interceptor.setBaseUrl(someOtherUrl);
        service.doB();
    }
}
```

---

As a third approach, you could also use *reflection* to just directly change base the base URL—I added this last just for completeness.

Answer (score 5):

You can implement `BaseUrl` and pass that instead of a fixed URL.[check out this link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1404)
Other approach is implementing `Endpoint` and make use of `setUrl()`.So for changing some header value at run time then you can use interceptor and add it to OkHttp.

Comment: This has changed. This is a gist implementing the new behaviour https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/8571a8207a5815cca1fb