# Is it possible to re-instantiate a Dagger 2 @Singleton?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

This might be a wrong approach, but I am trying to find a way to re-instantiate an underlying `Retrofit \ OkHttpClient` which is annotated with `@Singleton`.

The use case is that on the very first app start it will have a different URL. Then after the login and consecutive launches it will use the URL from the `SharedPreferences`. It looks like this

```
@Module
public class NetModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    WrapperClass providesAPI() {
        // underlying call with new Retrofit.Builder().client(okHttpClient).baseUrl(url)
        return new WrapperClass("someURLToProvision");
    }
}
```

And in the `Activity` I inject it with

```
 @Inject protected WrapperClass api;
```

After the provisioning I will no longer have the URL `someURLToProvision` but the actual URL which is stored in the `SharedPreferences`.

The question is: Can I re-instantiate the `Singleton` so it will not take the hard coded URL, but the one from the `SharedPreference`?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to do that is to recreate your Dagger component as the singleton is linked to it. See [here](https://www.techyourchance.com/dagger-2-scopes-demystified/) for more info about Dagger scopes

Comment: your OKHTTP must be singleton but the retrofit instance must be a Non-Singleton instance. Take a look at this project it implement what you want : https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/Firebase-Auth-Dagger-2

Comment: I just wanna link 2 similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36498131/1837367) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36769923/1837367) about how to scope/provide retrofit with different urls