# Dagger2+Retrofit change URL with Subcomponent : cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method

Tags: java, android, retrofit, dagger-2, rx-android

I'm newbie in Dagger .I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36779923/4306902) to change URL at Runtime.

Also I've used three modules and three components as shown below:

note : I have tow Components (`ApplicationComponent,ActivityComponent`) and one Subcomponent(`UrlComponent`) In additation I use `@Singletone`,`@PerUrl` and `@PerActivty` as a Scope.

When I want to `Inject` `RestApi` into  every Activity I encounter this Error :

```
 error: com.example.testdagger2.RestApi cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
com.example.dagger2.RestApi is injected at
com.example.dagger2.RestApiHelper.restApi
com.example.dagger2.RestApiHelper is injected at
com.example.dagger2.MainActivity.restApiHelper
com.example.testdagger2.MainActivity is injected at
com.example.testdagger2.di.component.ActivityComponent.inject(mainActivity)
```

Before I had to change the URL in Runtime, I had two Component and modules (appCompoent and activtyComponent), and all the  Providers (like Retrofit and RestApi ,...) were in the applicationModule and the program worked fine.

ApplicationComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(ExampleApplication exampleApplication);

    @ApplicationContext
    Context context();

    Application application();

    UrlComponent plus(UrlModule component);
}
```

ApplicationModule.java

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    private Application mApplication;

    public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
        this.mApplication = application;
    }

        @Provides
        @ApplicationContext
        Context provideContext() {
            return mApplication;
        }

        @Provides
        Application provideApplication() {
            return mApplication;
        }
    }
```

UrlComponent.java

```
@PerUrl
@Subcomponent(modules = UrlModule.class)
public interface UrlComponent {

}
```

UrlModule.java

```
@Module
public class UrlModule {
    private String url;

    public UrlModule(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerUrl
    OkHttpClient provideOkhttpClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @PerUrl
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(String baseURL, OkHttpClient client) {

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    RestApiHelper provideRestApiHelper(RestApiHelper restApiManager) {
        return restApiManager;
    }

    @Provides
    public RestApi provideApiService() {
        return provideRetrofit(url, provideOkhttpClient())
                .create(RestApi.class);

    }
}
```

ActivityComponent.java

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = ActivityModule.class,dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
  .
  .
  .

}
```

ActivityModule.java

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {

    private AppCompatActivity mActivity;

    public ActivityModule(AppCompatActivity mActivity) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }


    @Provides
    @ActivityContext
    Context provideContext() {
        return mActivity;
    }

    @Provides
    AppCompatActivity provideActivity() {
        return mActivity;
    }

   .
   .
   .

}
```

RestApi.java

```
public interface RestApi {

    Single<Object> getquestionlist(@Query("page") int page);

    Single<Object> getCategoryList();
}
```

RestApiHelper.java

```
public class RestApiHelper implements RestApi {

    @Inject
    RestApi restApi;

    @Inject
    public RestApiHelper(RestApi restApi) {
        this.restApi = restApi;
    }

    @Override
    public Single<Object> getquestionlist(int page) {
        return restApi.getquestionlist(1);
    }

    @Override
    public Single<Object> getCategoryList() {
        return restApi.getCategoryList();
    }
```

ExampleApplication.java

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {


    @Inject
    ApplicationComponent appComponent;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        appComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this)).build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
        appComponent.plus(new UrlModule("www/test/en"));


    }

    public ApplicationComponent getAppComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }


}
```

BaseActivity.java

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ActivityComponent activityComponent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //activityComponent=DaggerActivityComponent.builder().applicationModule()

        activityComponent= DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                .applicationComponent(((ExampleApplication)getApplication()).getAppComponent())
                .build();

    }

    public ActivityComponent getActivityComponent() {
        return activityComponent;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.jaqva

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {


    @Inject
    RestApiHelper restApiHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ActivityComponent component= getActivityComponent();
    component.inject(this);

        restApiHelper.getquestionlist(1).subscribe(new Consumer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Object o) throws Exception {

        }
    });
```

Now I have tow questions :

1-Shouldn't all the Providers built into the `Urlmodule` be added to `ApplicationModule`(`UrlModule is Subcomepoent of the ApplicationComponent` )

```
 @PerActivity
    @Component(modules = ActivityModule.class,dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class)
    public interface ActivityComponent {
```

and since the ApplicationComponent is an ActivityComponent dependencies, can all of these `Providers` be used in the ActivityComponent as well?

2-And as a basic question, where is the problem?

Comment: Remove `RestApiHelper` it's redundant. Just use `RestApi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't all the Providers built into the Urlmodule be added to
>   ApplicationModule(UrlModule is Subcomepoent of the
>   ApplicationComponent )

When you declare a component dependancy then the dependant component can only use the exposed dependencies which are declared inside the component class of `dependencies`, in your case these are `context` and `application` in your `ApplicationComponent` class and provided by `ApplicationModule`.

For validation(testing):

1) Add a new provides in your app module

```
// inside ApplicationModule
@Provides
Student getNum() {
    return new Student("aa");
}
```

2) Create and use `ActivityComponent` object to inject the `Student` in any class. It will result in missing provides. It can be fixed by exposing `Student` in `ApplicationComponent` class as:

```
Student getStu();
```

> 2-And as a basic question, where is the problem?

With the following implementations:

1. Dagger misconfigured dependancy graph, as explained above
2. Missing `Rxjava` implementation and retrofit implementations
3. Missing url provides etc

To fix the above follow the below steps:

> 1. Dagger misconfigured dependancy graph, as explained above

a) `MainActivity` requires the `RestApiHelper` which is provided by `UrlComponent` not `AppComponent` so first use `UrlComponent` as dependencies instead of `AppComponent`

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = ActivityModule.class, dependencies = {UrlComponent.class})
public interface ActivityComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

}
```

b) Now expose the dependancy in the `UrlComponent`

```
@PerUrl
@Subcomponent(modules = UrlModule.class)
public interface UrlComponent {
    RestApiHelper getRetrofit();
}
```

Implementation of `UrlModule.class` with fixed issues(mentioned above)

```
import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;    
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

@Module
public class UrlModule {
    private String url;

    public UrlModule(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerUrl
    OkHttpClient provideOkhttpClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    String provideUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerUrl
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(String baseURL, OkHttpClient client) {

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }


    @Provides
    RestApi provideApiService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(RestApi.class);
    }
}
```

c) Build Url `appComponent` and `urlComponent` in Application class for later use as

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {

    // note, I remove the inject, you were doing it for testing etc
    private ApplicationComponent appComponent;

    private UrlComponent urlComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        appComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this)).build();

        urlComponent = appComponent.plus(new UrlModule("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"));


    }

    public ApplicationComponent getAppComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }

    public UrlComponent getUrlComponent() {
        return urlComponent;
    }


}
```

Now build the `activityComponent` in `BaseActivity` as

```
activityComponent= DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
                .urlComponent(((ExampleApplication)getApplication()).getUrlComponent())
                .build();
```

and use it in your `MainActivity` as

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {


    @Inject
    RestApiHelper restApiHelper;
    Disposable disposable;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ActivityComponent component = getActivityComponent();
        component.inject(this);

        disposable = restApiHelper.getquestionlist(1)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Object o) throws Exception {
                        Log.d(TAG, "accept: "+ o.toString());    
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        disposable.dispose(); // best practice
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

That's it.

**Note**: Make sure your `baseUrl` value and `retrofit` objects are properly setup and have internet app permission etc. You can optimised your code further with lambdas etc as I kept most of the code as it is for understanding.

Comment: You made my day . Thank u

Comment: And now as another question:
How can I inject the Application module providers into the MainActivity ? @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: @hamidrezahaajhoseini  just add `Application getApplication();` (and others) in UrlComponent or you can add app module into activity component. I am glad that I could help, Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your method that provides RestApi is wrong.
I should be like

```
    @Provides
    public RestApi provideApiService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(RestApi.class);

    }
```

Comment: @pPaul Ost Yes, but the problem is not the issue