# Retrofit @Url doesnt override BaseUrl

Tags: android, kotlin, network-programming, retrofit2, restful-architecture

Hi i am trying to overide the baseUrl from one specific api call and it doesnt seem to work when using @Url as a paraemter to the api method.

Below is my Api class method

```
@POST
    fun getUserDetails(@Body body: request, @Url authUrl : String): Single<Response<ResponseData>>
```

code that cals and make the request

```
 private fun getApi(): Api {
        val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
        val httpClient = myNetworkHelper.createHttpClient()
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://defaultBaseUrl")
                .client(httpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()

        return retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
    }

 override fun getUserDetails(someRequestData, "http://dynamic/getuserDetails): Single<Response<ResponseData>> {
        return getApi().getUserDetails(body, url)
    }
```

The above results in making a request to this url

```
http://defaultBaseUrl/http://dynamic/getuserDetails
```

Instead of:

```
http://dynamic/getuserDetails
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the document from Retrofit `@GET` annotation:

```
@Documented 
@Target(METHOD) 
@Retention(RUNTIME) 
public @interface GET {   
/**
* A relative or absolute path, or full URL of the endpoint. This value is optional if the first
* parameter of the method is annotated with {@link Url @Url}.
* <p>    
* See {@linkplain retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder#baseUrl(HttpUrl) base URL} for details of how    
* this is resolved against a base URL to create the full endpoint URL.
*/   
    String value() default ""; 
}
```

So `@Url` should be placed as the first parameter, so I think this will work:

```
@POST
fun getUserDetails(@Url authUrl: String, @Body body: request): Single<Response<ResponseData>>
```

Comment: unfortunatly that did not work moving the parameters around . It still includes the base url

Comment: Did you try adding a `/` at the end of the base url, like `"http://defaultBaseUrl/"`

Comment: Can you provide any document? Maybe true because it works for me and mine is a GET request too

Comment: @TamHuynh try in a post and see what happens?

Comment: @jonney It's based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805689/retrofit-change-baseurl#comment65000178_38807371)

Comment: Actually checking in the source code there's no evidence of `@Url` working only with GET requests, so I don't know if that's actually true or not, I will search deeper

Comment: I will try it as soon as I can

Comment: Well I did a test with POST and the base url gets overridden if you use @Url in the first parameter.

Comment: It's a long time ago post and now I can confirm that too: First annotated `@Url` override works for both GET and POST

Answer (score 3):

I did a test in local and actually I've been able to override the base URL set in the Retrofit instance.

Here's the API:

```
public interface Api {

    @POST
    Call<Void> fakeService(@Url String url);
}
```

And here's the "client":

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Use the HttpLogginInterceptor to check what's the real call
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://www.foo.com/")
                .client(client)
                .build();

        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        Call<Void> call = api.fakeService("http://www.example.com");
        call.execute();
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
Jul 18, 2018 12:28:54 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> POST http://www.example.com/ (0-byte body)
Jul 18, 2018 12:28:55 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- 200 OK http://www.example.com/ (366ms, unknown-length body)
```