# Android Retrofit Change Dynamic BaseUrl by User

Tags: android, api, oop, kotlin, retrofit

I want to change `baseurl` with `spinner` by letting the user choose.
Because the api I use is also the baseurls are allocated to different servers.

Sample :

> euw1.site.com
>
> na1.site.com
>
> tr1.site.com

I want to make this server selection to the user with the `spinner`.
[App Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIJHJ.png)

As I am new to programming, I could not succeed no matter how hard I tried. Thank you to everyone who has already helped.

Answer (score 0):

[Retrofit - Change BaseUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805689/retrofit-change-baseurl) , change request get, post .. request url

```
@GET suspend fun getAPI(@Url url: String?): Response<Any> // url is dynamic
```