# How to change part of base url dynamically in retrofit android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I want to change part of base url at run time based on site selected by user. How this can be achieved using retrofit.

For eg.
Base URL : https://{siteCode}.prod.com/
where siteCode will be site selected by user at run time.

Currenly I have fixed base url in build.gradle.

```
 production {
            versionNameSuffix "-prod"

            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://vh.prod.com/\""
        }
```

How this can be made dynamic using retrofit.

Comment: Currently there is no way to change URL dynamically. The only way you can do that is by  creating different Retrofit instances.

Comment: You will have to save siteCode to shared prefs and create new retrofit instance everytime use changes siteCode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrofit - Change BaseUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805689/retrofit-change-baseurl)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the @Url annotation to pass a complete URL for an endpoint.

```kotlin
@GET
suspend fun getData(@Url String url): ResponseBody
```

The @Url parameter will replace the baseUrl set while creating the Retrofit instance.

Answer (score 0):

this is possible using retrofit interceptor, you can use multiple base url ..

```
public class HostSelectionInterceptor implements Interceptor {
private volatile String host;

public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = HttpUrl.parse(host).host();
}

@Override
public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    String reqUrl = request.url().host();

    String host = this.host;
    if (host != null) {
        HttpUrl newUrl = request.url().newBuilder()
            .host(host)
            .build();
        request = request.newBuilder()
            .url(newUrl)
            .build();
    }
    return chain.proceed(request);
}
```

}