# Dynamic Link crawl using Retrofit2

Tags: android, web-crawler, jsoup, retrofit2, whatsapp

I am implementing Link preview feature like WhatsApp, i.e

1. Provided any link, fetch all its Html
2. Crawl through Html, read all information
3. Display text and images

[image: WhatsApp Link Preview]

### **Jsoup Library**

I am successfully able to perform this using Jsoup library

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.techjuice.pk").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
```

It returns the html code of the page as a response.

---

### **Retrofit Library**

Now I wanted to perform the same task using Retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .build();
API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
Call<ResponseBody> call = api.crawlLink("http://techjuice.pk");
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

**API.class**

```
public interface API {

    @GET
    Call<ResponseBody> crawlLink(@Url String url);

}
```

**Exception**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Base URL required.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly you can't change URL in Retrofit at Runtime in that way.

Try this tutorial: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-change-api-base-url-at-runtime-2

or this answer: [Set dynamic base url using Retrofit 2.0 and Dagger 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498131/set-dynamic-base-url-using-retrofit-2-0-and-dagger-2)