# How to change base URL using retrofit2 and koin 2.0

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, koin

I have a query that returns a list of servers, and the user can select the server he needs.

Googling did not help, almost no results.

Tell me how to implement basic URL spoofing in real time using Koin and Retrofit?

**My Modules:**

```
fun createMainModule(context: Context) = module {

    single(named(APP_CONTEXT)) { context }

    single(named(RESOURCES)) { context.resources }

    single(named(REPOSITORY)) {
        Repository(get(named(RETROFIT)))
    }
}

fun createNetworkModule(baseUrl: String) = module(override = true) {

    single(named(TOKEN_INTERCEPTOR)) { createTokenInterceptor(get(named(DATA_PROVIDER))) }

    single(named(OK_HTTP)) { createOkHttpClient(get(named(TOKEN_INTERCEPTOR))) }

    single(named(GSON)) { createGson() }

    single(named(RETROFIT)) {
        createRetrofit(
            get(named(RESOURCES)),
            get(named(LOG_OUT_SUBJECT)),
            get(named(GSON)),
            baseUrl,
            get(named(OK_HTTP))
        )
}
```

Comment: The best thing to do would be to write an okhttp interceptor and update the base_url for every request. That's what I've done as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set dynamic base url using Retrofit 2.0 and Dagger 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498131/set-dynamic-base-url-using-retrofit-2-0-and-dagger-2)

Comment: Look into this: https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/8571a8207a5815cca1fb

Comment: Dagger 2 it's not Koin

Comment: @sonnet hmm, A good option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolve my problem with comment @sonnet 
This code:

```
class ChangeableBaseUrlInterceptor : Interceptor {
    @Volatile
    private var host: HttpUrl? = null

    fun setHost(host: String) {
        this.host = host.toHttpUrlOrNull()
    }

    fun clear() {
        host = null
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): okhttp3.Response {
        var request = chain.request()
        host?.let {
            val newUrl = request.url.newBuilder()
                .scheme(it.scheme)
                .host(it.toUrl().toURI().host)
                .port(it.port)
                .build()
            request = request.newBuilder().url(newUrl).build()
        }
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```