# android kotlin dagger 2 change base_url

Tags: android, retrofit, dagger-2

I want to change base_url from my Retrofit which I build in dagger 2. I have this :

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideNewsService(): ApiServices {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
        .build()
        .create(ApiServices::class.java)
}
```

and when my app is running I want to change a value base_url , how I can do this ?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498131/set-dynamic-base-url-using-retrofit-2-0-and-dagger-2

Comment: Add info where are you storing this `BASE_URL`

Comment: @Boken my BASE_URL is a Constans in class

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? Have a dynamic base_url at runtime?

Comment: @sonnet yes I have