# Assisted Injection using Dagger Hilt and Provides annotation

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I'm using `dagger hilt` as a dependency injection framework in my project, however, I have this situation where I need to provide `Retrofit` instance. Normally I do it using the `@Provides` annotation.

```kotlin
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(
        okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        scalarsConverterFactory: ScalarsConverterFactory,
    ): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(scalarsConverterFactory)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
```

But now I came to a situation where I need to have a dynamic `BASE_URL`. In normal cases when the class is created by me, I use the `@AssestedFactory` and `@AssestedInject` annotations.

How to use the `@AssestedFactory` to provide a dynamic `BASE_URL` in my situation.

Comment: Create a retrofit factory class, and a create method which takes in the dynamic url and builds the retrofit instance when needed?

Comment: How dynamic do you need it? Is it sufficient to bind a `@BaseUrl String` (using a qualifier you create) into the dependency graph and then pass it as a `@Provides` function parameter? Or do you need to be able to change the BASE_URL during the lifetime of the app, which suggests that the Retrofit instance shouldn't be as `@Singleton` as it appears in your posted code?

Comment: @JeffBowman What I mean is that the `BASE_URL` can be changed during the runtime.  Considering your point of changing the `@Singleton` to another scope. How can I inject the `BASE_URL` into the retrofit instance?

Comment: Per https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1404#issuecomment-207408548 this isn't possible in Retrofit 2; you'll need to follow the instructions at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36498131/1426891). Suggesting this as a dupe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set dynamic base url using Retrofit 2.0 and Dagger 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498131/set-dynamic-base-url-using-retrofit-2-0-and-dagger-2)