# How can i pass runtime dependepcy to Hilt module?

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-hilt

I wish to create a `Retrofit` instance via Hilt module with runtime `baseUrl`. How can I provide `baseUrl` to Hilt module? Graph example: `use case -> repository -> api -> retrofit -> ...`.

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Should be done same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498131/set-dynamic-base-url-using-retrofit-2-0-and-dagger-2.

Comment: I'm asking about hilt-way of solution. Interceptor is interesting solution, but maybe it is possible to provide dependencies to hilt modules?